# Comprehensive path to globally changing an Ember application name

Tags: ember.js

I built an Ember app with CLI and 2.0 – it was an app for hats made of plants, so I named it "plant-hat."

A few months later, I realized that people didn't really like wearing plants on their heads, so I retooled it to sell "Shoes filled with worms." *I think this time it'll really take off*.

So, I want to rename the app and any important parts of it - as if I built it as "shoes-with-worms" from the beginning.

What steps do I take so that I don't miss anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TBH, I would buy hats made of plants...

Lol, but seriously:

Here are the locations of where the app name is **excluding** things that you have created, i.e. these are the locations where ember-cli puts your app name by default:

package.json:

```
"name": "...",
```

environment.js:

```
modulePrefix: '...',
```

bower.json

```
"name": "...",
```

app/index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/....css">
<script src="assets/....js"></script>
```

tests/index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/....css">
<script src="assets/....js"></script>
```

Replace `...` with your new app name.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm betting this is it - but I haven't had a chance to try it yet. Soon! I *actually named the app `r` -- not so good for a a find and replace... ; )

Comment: Add this one to the answer and I'll mark it! `<script src="assets/....js"></script>`

Comment: Updated the original post.

Comment: For tests/index.html - title css and js need to be changed too.

Comment: Updated the OP again. Thanks.

Comment: `package-lock.json` too // great. another thing I need to know about! hehe

Answer (score 4):

cd into your app, `ember init --name=shoes-filled-with-worms`  review the diffs

Comment: This works best. Also recommended here: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/2251

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me -

`rm -rf node_modules/ dist/`

`grep -nr 'current-project-name*' .`

This will return around 8-10 files (if you haven't used the name in your app). You can then make the changes manually or automate it like so --

`grep -nr 'current-project-name*' . | xargs sed -i 's/current-project-name/new-app-name/g'`

You will need to do `npm install` to reinstall the node modules

--

I am using ember 2.15.1 and had to change the following files -

```
./tests/index.html 
./tests/unit/initializers/ember-simple-auth-test.js
./package-lock.json
./app/index.html
./README.md
./package.json
./config/environment.js
./bower.json
```